# Cola de prioridad descendente

Tags: java

estoy trabajando en una cola de prioridad descendente.
El cadenero dejará pasar a las personas de acuerdo con su sexo y economía. La prioridad debe darse de la siguiente manera:

1. Personas de sexo femenino.
2. Personas que tienen más dinero.

   Ejemplo:
   [Juana/F/500.5, Pedro/M/10000, Violeta/F/600, Carlos/M/20500]

   El orden en que entrarán al antro será:
3. Violeta 2. Juana 3. Carlos 4. Pedro.
   El número de personas en la cola de espera debe estar entre 10 y 20
   (considerando también al 10 y al 20), el número se generará aleatoriamente.
   Los nombres y el dinero que cada persona carga también se generará aleatoriamente. Me imprime los nombres de manera aleatoria pero mis metodos para encolar, eliminar, agregar, no funcionan. Espero puedan ayudarme.

Adjunto lo que he intentado:

**Class Persona:**

```
package persona;

public class Persona <Persona> {

    private String nombres_h;
    private int dinero; 
    private String nombres_m;
    public Persona(String nombres_m,String nombres_h, int dinero) {
        this.nombres_h = nombres_h;
        this.dinero = dinero;
        this.nombres_m=nombres_m;
    }
    public String getNombres_m() {
        return nombres_m;
    }
    public void setNombres_m(String nombres_m) {
        this.nombres_m = nombres_m;
    }

    public String getNombres_h() {
        return nombres_h;
    }

    public void setNombres_h(String nombres_h) {
        this.nombres_h = nombres_h;
    }

    public int getDinero() {
        return dinero;
    }

    public void setDinero(int dinero) {
        this.dinero = dinero;
    }
}
```

**Class Colapriorizada:**

```
package persona;

import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Colapriorizada <Persona extends Comparable<Persona>>  {

    private Nodo<Persona> inicio;
    private Nodo<Persona> fin;
    private int tamanio;

    private void validarIndice(int indice) {
        if(isVacia() 
            || (indice < 0 
               || indice >= tamanio))
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    public void agregar(Persona elemento) {
        Nodo<Persona> nuevo = new Nodo<>(elemento);

        if (isVacia()) {
            inicio = fin = nuevo;
        }
        else {
            fin.setDerecho(nuevo);
            nuevo.setIzquierdo(fin);
            fin = nuevo;
        }

        tamanio++;
    }

    public void agregar(int indice, Persona elemento) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    public Persona eliminar(int indice) {
        validarIndice(indice);

        Persona elemento = null;
        if(tamanio == 1) {
            elemento = inicio.getElemento();
            inicio = fin = null;
        } else if(indice == 0) {
            elemento = inicio.getElemento();
            inicio = inicio.getDerecho();
            inicio.setIzquierdo(null);
        } else if(indice == tamanio-1) {
            elemento = fin.getElemento();
            fin = fin.getIzquierdo();
            fin.setDerecho(null);
        } else {
            Nodo<Persona> auxiliar = inicio;
            for (int i = 0; i < indice; i++) {
                auxiliar = auxiliar.getDerecho();
            }

            elemento = auxiliar.getElemento();
            auxiliar.getDerecho()
                .setIzquierdo(
                    auxiliar
                        .getIzquierdo());
            auxiliar.getIzquierdo()
                .setDerecho(
                    auxiliar
                        .getDerecho());
        }

        tamanio--;
        return elemento;
    }

    public void eliminar(Persona elemento) {
        int indice = indiceDe(elemento);

        if (indice != -1) {
            eliminar(indice);
        }
        else {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
    }

    public int indiceDe(Persona elemento) {
        int indice = 0;

        for (Nodo<Persona> auxiliar = inicio; 
            auxiliar != null; 
            auxiliar = auxiliar.getDerecho(),
                indice++) {
            if(auxiliar.getElemento()
                    .equals(elemento))
                return indice;
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public Persona get(int indice) {
        validarIndice(indice);

        Nodo<Persona> auxiliar = inicio;
        for (int i = 0; i < indice; i++) {
            auxiliar = auxiliar.getDerecho();
        }

        return auxiliar.getElemento();
    }

    public boolean isVacia() {
        return inicio == null;
    }

    public int tamanio() {
        return tamanio;
    }
}
```

**Class Nodo:**

```
package persona;

public class Nodo<E> {
    private Nodo<E> izquierdo;
    private E elemento;
    private Nodo<E> Derecho;

    public Nodo(E elemento) {
        this.elemento = elemento;
    }

    public Nodo(Nodo<E> izquierdo, E elemento, Nodo<E> Derecho) {
        this.izquierdo = izquierdo;
        this.elemento = elemento;
        this.Derecho = Derecho;
    }

    public Nodo<E> getDerecho() {
        return Derecho;
    }

    public void setDerecho(Nodo<E> Derecho) {
        this.Derecho = Derecho;
    }

    public Nodo<E> getIzquierdo() {
        return izquierdo;
    }

    public void setIzquierdo(Nodo<E> izquierdo) {
        this.izquierdo = izquierdo;
    }

    public E getElemento() {
        return elemento;
    }

    public void setElemento(E elemento) {
        this.elemento = elemento;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return elemento.toString();
    }
}
```

**Main:**

```
package persona; 

import java.util.Random;

public class PruebaANTRO {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] nombres_h={"JUAN","JOSÉ LUIS","JOSÉ","FRANCISCO","ANTONIO","JESÚS","MIGUEL ÁNGEL","PEDRO","ALEJANDRO","MANUEL"};
        String[] nombres_m= {"MARÍA GUADALUPE","GUADALUPE","MARÍA","JUANA"," MARGARITA"," MARÍA DEL CARMEN","VANESSA","JANETTHE","FERNANDA","DANIELA"};
        int dinero;
        Random rand = new Random();
        for(int i=0; i<10;i++) {
            int n =rand.nextInt(10);
            int z =rand.nextInt(10);
            dinero=(rand.nextInt(100000)+1);

            String h= nombres_h[n];
            String m=nombres_m[z];
            Persona persona = new Persona(h,m,dinero);

//             if(persona !=null ){
//                if("MARIA GUADALUPE".equals(persona.getNombres_m())){
//                    listaAzul.add(persona);
//               }else if("GUADALUPE".equals(persona.getNombres_m())){
//                    listaAmarillo.add(persona);
//                }else if("MARIA".equals(persona.getNombres_m())){
//                    listacafe.add(persona);
//                }else if("JUANA".equals(persona.getNombres_m())){
//                    listaPurpura.add(persona);
//                }else if("MARGARITA".equals(persona.getNombres_m())){
//                    listaRosa.add(persona);
//                }else if("MARIA DEL CARMEN".equals(persona.getNombres_m())){
//                    listacafe.add(persona);
//                }else if("VANESSA".equals(persona.getNombres_m())){
//                    listaPurpura.add(persona);
//                }else if("JANETTHE".equals(persona.getNombres_m())){
//                    listaRosa.add(persona);
//                }else if("VANESSA".equals(persona.getNombres_m())){
//                    listaPurpura.add(persona);
//                }else if("JANETTHE".equals(persona.getNombres_m())){
//                    listaRosa.add(persona);
//                }    



            System.out.println("NOMBRE:"+h + "\n DINERO: " + persona.getDinero()+"\n");
            System.out.println("NOMBRE:"+m + "\n DINERO: " + persona.getDinero()+"\n");
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Tiene que ser una cola creada por ti sí o sí?

Comment: tienes un montón de errores en cuanto a genéricos: `Persona` está parametrizada sobre sí misma y no entiendo por qué necesitas hacer eso. `ColaPriorizada` está parametrizada sobre un tipo que ha de ser `Persona` pero que extienda Comparable (cosa que `Persona` no hace)... por qué no te quitas todos estos problemas y usas `Comparator`para comparar?

Comment: Además parece que no estás definiendo una cola de prioridad sino una lista enlazada...